# New to Web development not sure how to fix reactjs errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs

These is a long page full for error messages and I cannot get hold of the person teaching this class been 2 weeks. I tried redoing it but I still got the same messages I do not know how or what to do in order to fix them.  Here is the git hub link: https://github.com/SadiaSanam/petshop

And these are the messages, how to I fix it? Because some of those pages I cannot even find..

TypeError: path.split is not a function
get
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/src/utils/get.ts:6

```html
TypeError: path.split is not a function
get
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/src/utils/get.ts:6
  3 | import isUndefined from './isUndefined';
  4 | 
  5 | export default (obj: any = {}, path: string, defaultValue?: unknown) => {
> 6 |   const result = compact(path.split(/[,[\].]+?/)).reduce(
  7 |     (result, key) => (isNullOrUndefined(result) ? result : result[key]),
  8 |     obj,
  9 |   );
View compiled
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/src/useForm.ts:967
  964 | 
  965 | const register: UseFormRegister<TFieldValues> = React.useCallback(
  966 |   (name, options) => {
> 967 |     const isInitialRegister = !get(fieldsRef.current, name);
      | ^  968 | 
  969 |     set(fieldsRef.current, name, {
  970 |       _f: {
View compiled
Login
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/src/components/Login.js:88
  85 | <div className='form-control'>
  86 |  
  87 |   <label htmlFor='email'>Email</label>
> 88 |   <input type='email' name='email' id='email' ref={register( {required:true})  }   />
     | ^  89 |   { errors.email ? <span className='err'> email is required!</span> : null } 
  90 | 
  91 |   <label htmlFor='password'>Password</label>
View compiled
renderWithHooks
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14985
  14982 |   }
  14983 | }
  14984 | 
> 14985 | var children = Component(props, secondArg); // Check if there was a render phase update
        | ^  14986 | 
  14987 | if (didScheduleRenderPhaseUpdateDuringThisPass) {
  14988 |   // Keep rendering in a loop for as long as render phase updates continue to
View compiled
mountIndeterminateComponent
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17811
  17808 | 
  17809 |   setIsRendering(true);
  17810 |   ReactCurrentOwner$1.current = workInProgress;
> 17811 |   value = renderWithHooks(null, workInProgress, Component, props, context, renderLanes);
        | ^  17812 |   setIsRendering(false);
  17813 | } // React DevTools reads this flag.
  17814 | 
View compiled
beginWork
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19049
  19046 | switch (workInProgress.tag) {
  19047 |   case IndeterminateComponent:
  19048 |     {
> 19049 |       return mountIndeterminateComponent(current, workInProgress, workInProgress.type, renderLanes);
        | ^  19050 |     }
  19051 | 
  19052 |   case LazyComponent:
View compiled
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3945
  3942 | function callCallback() {
  3943 |   didCall = true;
  3944 |   restoreAfterDispatch();
> 3945 |   func.apply(context, funcArgs);
       | ^  3946 |   didError = false;
  3947 | } // Create a global error event handler. We use this to capture the value
  3948 | // that was thrown. It's possible that this error handler will fire more
View compiled
invokeGuardedCallbackDev
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3994
  3991 | // errors, it will trigger our global error handler.
  3992 | 
  3993 | evt.initEvent(evtType, false, false);
> 3994 | fakeNode.dispatchEvent(evt);
       | ^  3995 | 
  3996 | if (windowEventDescriptor) {
  3997 |   Object.defineProperty(window, 'event', windowEventDescriptor);
View compiled
invokeGuardedCallback
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4056
  4053 | function invokeGuardedCallback(name, func, context, a, b, c, d, e, f) {
  4054 |   hasError = false;
  4055 |   caughtError = null;
> 4056 |   invokeGuardedCallbackImpl$1.apply(reporter, arguments);
  4057 | }
  4058 | /**
  4059 |  * Same as invokeGuardedCallback, but instead of returning an error, it stores
View compiled
beginWork$1
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23964
  23961 | } // Run beginWork again.
  23962 | 
  23963 | 
> 23964 | invokeGuardedCallback(null, beginWork, null, current, unitOfWork, lanes);
        | ^  23965 | 
  23966 | if (hasCaughtError()) {
  23967 |   var replayError = clearCaughtError(); // `invokeGuardedCallback` sometimes sets an expando `_suppressLogging`.
View compiled
performUnitOfWork
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22776
  22773 | 
  22774 | if ( (unitOfWork.mode & ProfileMode) !== NoMode) {
  22775 |   startProfilerTimer(unitOfWork);
> 22776 |   next = beginWork$1(current, unitOfWork, subtreeRenderLanes);
        | ^  22777 |   stopProfilerTimerIfRunningAndRecordDelta(unitOfWork, true);
  22778 | } else {
  22779 |   next = beginWork$1(current, unitOfWork, subtreeRenderLanes);
View compiled
workLoopSync
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22707
  22704 | function workLoopSync() {
  22705 |   // Already timed out, so perform work without checking if we need to yield.
  22706 |   while (workInProgress !== null) {
> 22707 |     performUnitOfWork(workInProgress);
  22708 |   }
  22709 | }
  22710 | 
View compiled
renderRootSync
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22670
  22667 | 
  22668 | do {
  22669 |   try {
> 22670 |     workLoopSync();
        | ^  22671 |     break;
  22672 |   } catch (thrownValue) {
  22673 |     handleError(root, thrownValue);
View compiled
performSyncWorkOnRoot
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22293
  22290 |   }
  22291 | } else {
  22292 |   lanes = getNextLanes(root, NoLanes);
> 22293 |   exitStatus = renderRootSync(root, lanes);
        | ^  22294 | }
  22295 | 
  22296 | if (root.tag !== LegacyRoot && exitStatus === RootErrored) {
View compiled
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11327
  11324 |     var callback = _queue[i];
  11325 | 
  11326 |     do {
> 11327 |       callback = callback(_isSync2);
        | ^  11328 |     } while (callback !== null);
  11329 |   }
  11330 | });
View compiled
unstable_runWithPriority
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:468
  465 | currentPriorityLevel = priorityLevel;
  466 | 
  467 | try {
> 468 |   return eventHandler();
      | ^  469 | } finally {
  470 |   currentPriorityLevel = previousPriorityLevel;
  471 | }
View compiled
runWithPriority$1
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11276
  11273 | 
  11274 | function runWithPriority$1(reactPriorityLevel, fn) {
  11275 |   var priorityLevel = reactPriorityToSchedulerPriority(reactPriorityLevel);
> 11276 |   return Scheduler_runWithPriority(priorityLevel, fn);
  11277 | }
  11278 | function scheduleCallback(reactPriorityLevel, callback, options) {
  11279 |   var priorityLevel = reactPriorityToSchedulerPriority(reactPriorityLevel);
View compiled
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11322
  11319 | try {
  11320 |   var _isSync2 = true;
  11321 |   var _queue = syncQueue;
> 11322 |   runWithPriority$1(ImmediatePriority$1, function () {
        | ^  11323 |     for (; i < _queue.length; i++) {
  11324 |       var callback = _queue[i];
  11325 | 
View compiled
flushSyncCallbackQueue
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11309
  11306 |     Scheduler_cancelCallback(node);
  11307 |   }
  11308 | 
> 11309 |   flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl();
  11310 | }
  11311 | 
  11312 | function flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl() {
View compiled
discreteUpdates$1
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22420
  22417 |     if (executionContext === NoContext) {
  22418 |       // Flush the immediate callbacks that were scheduled during this batch
  22419 |       resetRenderTimer();
> 22420 |       flushSyncCallbackQueue();
        | ^  22421 |     }
  22422 |   }
  22423 | }
View compiled
discreteUpdates
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3756
  3753 | isInsideEventHandler = true;
  3754 | 
  3755 | try {
> 3756 |   return discreteUpdatesImpl(fn, a, b, c, d);
       | ^  3757 | } finally {
  3758 |   isInsideEventHandler = prevIsInsideEventHandler;
  3759 | 
View compiled
dispatchDiscreteEvent
C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/SheCodes/Full stack/app/petshop/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:5889
  5886 |     flushDiscreteUpdatesIfNeeded(nativeEvent.timeStamp);
  5887 |   }
  5888 | 
> 5889 |   discreteUpdates(dispatchEvent, domEventName, eventSystemFlags, container, nativeEvent);
  5890 | }
  5891 | 
  5892 | function dispatchUserBlockingUpdate(domEventName, eventSystemFlags, container, nativeEvent) {
View compiled
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `path.split` ? As in, how do you want to split it up?

Answer (score 1):

TO use react-hook-forms, theres some fix to work:

#### The inputs fields calls the register function. This function has 2 params:

```
register(field_name <- string, options <- object);
```

In your case, you need to call it like that:

```
<input type='email' name='email' id='email' ref={register("email", {required:true})  }   />

<input type='password' name='password' id='password' 
                 ref={register("password", {required:true, minLength:6, maxLength: 10} )} />
```

#### You're calling the error object the wrong way. Thats how you should call it:

```
const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }, reset  } = useForm();
```

#### The last error I found after the fix is about the way you call register function.

You are setting the register at the ref property. According to the docs, you should just set the register in the component, and this will return all the props:

```
<input type='email' id='email' {...register("email", {required:true})  }   />
```

Here at the Sources, you can read and deep in "why am I doing this?" =):

register():
https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register

errors:
https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformstate/errormessage

---

I'll add here some tips to help you found the solution to new errors:

- Make a path to discover where to focus: When you have an error, you need to found exactly what's causing it. In your case, the console was accusing a file that isn't even in your main folders (that was a dependency). In that case, remove code, try to delete some code, and see if the project works. If works, you now is somewhere there, and do again filtering the removed code.
- Go to the official docs/demos and compare your code: I've never used react-hook-forms, But a look at the docs helps me to find the errors.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, it helped to fix the login page. however, I am still struggling with so many error messages when I hit the register page 'TypeError: path.split is not a function' and such that. I do not understand.

Comment: So, i checked your Register page file, and there're the same errors we found at Login page. Try to fix them just like the Login fixes.

Comment: npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm create-react-app .
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: I keep getting this text now? Is there a way to understand these strings easier? I get confused and feel lost (It has barely been 6 months since I started learning.)

Comment: Actually, research and time to get these error messages easier. But how I talk before, try to undo changes in your project, so you can found what's wrong. A good practice starting is do just a little bit of code, and check if it's working. This way, if you do some mistake, i will discover just in time.
About the npm error, it appears to be cause by some change in your folder project or in npm itself. Maybe the cli you're using. Maybe anything haha. Try search by the first line on google.

Comment: okay. I will work on it. Thank you!